# Disposing a UserControl loaded via ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls

i have the following code on my mainView (Window)

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="OnLoadChildView">Load</Button>
    <Button Click="OnUnloadChildView">UnLoad</Button>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ChildViewModel}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and this code on my ChildView (UserControl)

```
<StackPanel>
    <local:MyListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    </local:MyListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

this is the code of the MainView

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainViewModel vm = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = vm;
}

public MainViewModel Model { get { return this.DataContext as MainViewModel; } }

private void OnLoadChildView(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Model.ChildViewModel = new ChildViewModel();
}

private void OnUnloadChildView(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Model.ChildViewModel = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
}
```

and here my other code:

```
public class MyListBox : ListBox
{
    public MyListBox() { Debug.WriteLine("Created instance of MyListBox:" + this.GetHashCode()); }
    ~MyListBox() { Debug.WriteLine("destroyed instance of MyListBox:" + this.GetHashCode()); }
}

public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PropertyChangedEventHandler _propertyChanged;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged
    {
        add
        {
            _propertyChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _propertyChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (_propertyChanged != null)
        {
            _propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private ChildViewModel _ChildViewModel;
    public ChildViewModel ChildViewModel
    {
        get { return _ChildViewModel; }
        set
        {
            if (_ChildViewModel != value)
            {
                _ChildViewModel = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ChildViewModel));
            }
        }
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ChildViewModel()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Created instance of ChildViewModel:" + this.GetHashCode());
        this.Items = new List<string>(new string[] { "ABC", "DEF" });
    }

    ~ChildViewModel()
    {
        this.Items = null;
        Debug.WriteLine("destroyed instance of ChildViewModel:" + this.GetHashCode());
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> _Items;
    public IEnumerable<string> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            if (_Items != value)
            {
                _Items = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Items));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I adress the view using app resources:

```
 <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildViewModel}">
            <vw:ChildView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
```

When I start the app and click on the load button, and then the unload button a couple of times I get this output:

```
Created instance of ChildViewModel:2670961
Created instance of ChildView:2080614
Created instance of MyListBox:33397791
destroyed instance of ChildViewModel:2670961
```

When I change the XAML of the ChildView to:

```
   <StackPanel>
        <local:MyListBox>
        </local:MyListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

so removing the Binding, start my up app up again, click the load button and then the unload button a couple of times I get this:

```
Created instance of ChildViewModel:30767036
Created instance of ChildView:50297887
Created instance of MyListBox:5453341
destroyed instance of MyListBox:5453341
destroyed instance of ChildViewModel:30767036
Destroyed instance of ChildView:50297887
```

So it seems that I can't really can't get rid of the NotifyPropertyChangedEventHandler of the WPF, so my listbox and my view won't get disposed. How can I achieve this? Because I think it's clearing, removing the Binding is not an option.

Comment: Can you show the `ViewModelBase` class code?

Comment: Thats from the Galasoft.MvvmLight Namespace

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I don't have that `Galasoft` thing (whatever it is). In order to achieve your goal, you need to have access to the class where the PropertyChanged event is defined.

Comment: I changed it to use my own ViewModelBase, as expected it does not change anything.

Comment: Sorry, I was mislead that the problem is caused by NotifyPropertyChangedEventHandler, but it's not. When your unload code is executed, `ContentPresenter.Content` property is cleared, but `ContentPresenter.DataContext` is not (at least not immediately - that happens later outside of the user code)

Comment: Could this be some kind of hardware-setting/ .net Framework oder Windows Problem? Because I tried this on another machine today, running Windows 7 instead of windows 8.1, and on the win7 machine, the cleanup works perfect.
The exact same project (copied all files) is built on both machines in Debug-Mode, both using VS2015. The project is set to Framework 4.5

Comment: Have no idea. Actually I've tried your original code on my laptop (Win8.1 originally, now Win10-:) and it works as expected (with and w/o binding). It happens at the second click (due to deferred layout processing of WPF). I would not worry too much about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'm closing this, because actually the cleanup is built the right way, but it seems that the GarbageCollector is taking itsself really some time to think about cleaning things up on the win8.1 machine. After about clicking 10-15 times on the Unload Button, the cleanup occurs. On the win7 machine, the cleanup occurs always at the second click.